# Relative paths to images Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a question. I'm working on a sheet which contains links to a folder of images in my computer. This sheet will be sent to a colleague. My aim is that being able to do a relative path, that when he'll click on the link the image shows up without updating the path. 
if you have any suggestions tell me.
Regards!

Comment: Does your colleague's computer have access to the folder in your computer? If so, what is the connection method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible if the images are stored on your local C:\drive if you are not networked together. A path "C:\example\path\to\image.jpg", when parsed by his PC will look on HIS local drive at that location, and the image won't be there.

If you both have access to a sharepoint or something I would store the image there and use a path to that using an IP address if at all possible. E.g "\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\example\path\to\image.jpg".

If both users have access to the share then the image will be displayed properly without changing the path.

Alternatively, although I haven't tested this, if you were networked together within a domain for example, and were both discoverable with the relevant ntfs and share permissions, I would see no reason why you couldn't substitute your own IP address for the share IP in the example above, and have the image fetched that way from your PC.